# how do I add a string to a json value in python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So I'm trying to setup json so i can store data in-between user sessions I like a name but i don't know how to add or change a specific value in an external json file like for example `{"name": ""}` how do i fill that `""` for the json file using python?

I have already tried to use dumps and all the tutorials use dumps

## the json in another file

```
{
  "human_name": "",
  "oracle_name": "",
  "human_age": "",
  "human_gender": "",
  "oracle_gender": ""
}
```

## the python

```
import json

with open('data.json', '+') as filedata:
    data = filedata.read()

used_data = json.loads(data)

if str(used_data(['human_name'])) == "":
    print("what is your name")
    name = input()
    json.dumps(name)
    if str(used_data(['oracle_name'])) == "":
        print("what is my name")
        oracle_name = input()
        json.dumps(oracle_name)
print(str(['human_name']))
```

The expected result is when I print the data it displays input, but when i run it it goes

> File "rember.py", line 3, in 
>       with open('data.json', '+') as filedata: ValueError: Must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode and at most one plus

Comment: Your syntax is off. After `json.loads`, you're left with a dictionary, so you would access it by key. However, `used_data(['human_name'])` treats `used_data` as a callable (a function) and you're passing the list `['human_name']` as a parameter. Get rid of the `()`.

Comment: The error itself is due to how you're trying to read the file. What do you intend `+` to do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

[`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) loads the entire json string as a python `dict` object. The values in a `dict` are changed/added using `dict[key] = value`. You can't call a dict object to change its value.

The [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) method serializes an object to a JSON formatted str. Which you can then write into the same file or a different file based on your requirement.

```py
import json


with open('data.json', 'r') as filedata:
    data = filedata.read()

    used_data = json.loads(data)

    if used_data['human_name'] == "":
        print("what is your name")
        name = input()
        used_data['human_name'] = name

        if used_data['oracle_name'] == "":
            print("what is my name")
            oracle_name = input()
            used_data['oracle_name'] = oracle_name

print(used_data)

with open('data.json', 'w') as filewrite:
    filewrite.write(json.dumps(used_data, indent=4))
```

Comment: There's no need for `dumps` and `loads` here, just use `dump` and `load`

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need to do is load json file as dictionary, add value, and save it.

```
import json
with open('./data.json', 'r') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
d['human_name'] = 'steve'
d['oracle_name'] = 'maria'
with open('./data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f, indent=4)
```